# Cannot open and write contents to file on AWS EC2 in PHP Script

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using this code to read the file and add new data at the end of file.

`$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");`

The problem is that this code works fine on local server but giving an error of `can't open file` on Amazon EC2 server.

Also file i use the parameter `r` instead of `a` it works but i can't understand why isn't the `a` parameter working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen if you don't have write permissions. So you can try to get the error. Remove your die and use the following command to get the error.

`error_get_last()` as example:

```
print_r(error_get_last());
```

This should give you the last error for fopen.

Comment: Its showing this array `(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => fopen(logs/log.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied
    [file] => /var/www/html/ibin/index.php
    [line] => 20
)`

Comment: There you have your error ;) "Permission denied"... you have to set write permission to destination file you try to open.

Comment: i have set permission to the whole logs folder through ssh still the same error

Answer (score 1):

The `r` parameter is opening for reading. The `a` parameter is for *append*, so it may return an error if you do not have write access to the file in question.